# Jquery append div depend on select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create this option here.. The user can choose how many rooms he wants.

When he selects I am appending with JQuery the number of rooms he choosed.

Then he can choose how many adults and children there will be in each room. But when he choose for children I want to append another choice (age of children) depend on how many children.

As you can see I can add the rooms but on children I get all the problems.

1.)When I am adding the number of children i can not make it append only on specific div. And children option is working only for the first one.

2.)I tried to hide children age boxes like the rooms but I can not make it work.

Any feedback on what am i doing wrong would be helpful.

Thanks

So this is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //onchange of rooms-count
  $('#search_rooms_select').change(function() {
    var roomsSelected = $('#search_rooms_select option:selected').val();
    var roomsDisplayed = $('[id^="room-"]:visible').length;
    var roomsRendered = $('[id^="room-"]').length;

    //if room count is greater than number displayed - add or show accordingly
    if (roomsSelected > roomsDisplayed) {
      for (var i = 1; i <= roomsSelected; i++) {
        var r = $('#room-' + i);
        if (r.length == 0) {
          var clone = $('#room-1').clone(); //clone
          clone.children(':first').text("Room: ");
          //change ids appropriately
          setNewID(clone, i);
          clone.children('div').children('select').each(function() {
            setNewID($(this), i);
          });
          $(clone).insertAfter($('#room-' + roomsRendered));
        } else {
          //if the room exists and is hidden 
          $(r).show();
        }
      }
    } else {
      //else if less than room count selected - hide
      for (var i = ++roomsSelected; i <= roomsRendered; i++) {
        $('#room-' + i).hide();
      }
    }
  });

  function setNewID(elem, i) {
    oldID = elem.attr('id');
    newId = oldID.substring(0, oldID.indexOf('-')) + "-" + i;
    elem.attr('id', newId);
  }

  $('[id^="children-"]').change(function() {

    var kidsSelected = $('[id^="children-"] option:selected').val();

    for (i = 1; i <= kidsSelected; i++) {
      var htmlChildren = "<div class='col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4'><span class='labelselect'>Child 1</span><select class='form-control' id='childrenage" + i + "'><option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></div> ";
      $(".childrendiv").append(htmlChildren);
    }
    var kidsDisplayed = $('[id^="childrenage-"]:visible').length;
    var kidsRendered = $('[id^="childrenage-"]').length;


  });
});
```

```css
label {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class='content' id='passengers-popover' style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label class="search_rooms_input" for="search_rooms_input">Rooms:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <select name="" class="form-control" id="search_rooms_select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 paddinglr labelform">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 paddingright">
      <label class="labelselect"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 paddinglr">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 paddingright">
        <label>Adults</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 paddingright">
        <label>Children(0-16)</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" id="room-1">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <label>
        Room:
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 paddinglr">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" id='adults-1'>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" id='children-1'>
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="childrendiv"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="continue">Continue</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you're attaching the change event to the children select element, only the first one exists. When more rooms are added, and new children select elements created, they don't have the change event attached to them. This is the classic "dynamic form field element and event binding issue" (see link). Also, take a careful look at how you're assigning IDs because I was able to run the code and get duplicates by flipping back and forth between 0 children and non-0.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements#9331127

Comment: What @LavaWings pointed is right, and besides that, you're selecting the childreen select by ID, and the code are not changing the id, all selects are with same ID. In `change` event, you can use $(this), instead of the ID of element.